# How to display the contents of a directory

Tags: java

I need to write a recursive algorithm to display the contents of a directory in a computer's file system but I am very new to Java. Does anyone have any code or a good tutorial on how to access a directory in a file system with Java??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**JFileChooser**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) class, check this [**example**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm).

Optionally you can also execute native commands like `DIR` , `ls`using java , here is an [example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-execute-a-command-from-code.html)

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I needed to piece things together.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Jigar, I think that I just voted up for your answer.  If I didn't please let me know.  Thanks,  Doug

Comment: @doug no you didn't :) just letting you know

Answer (score 1):

This took me way too long to write and test, but here's something that should work.

Note: You can pass in either a string or file.

Note 2: This is a naive implementation.  Not only is it single-threaded, but it does not check to see if files are links, and could get stuck in an endless loop due to this.

Note 3: The lines immediately after comments can be replaced with your own implementation.

```
import java.io.*;

public class DirectoryRecurser {

    public static void parseFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            parseFile(file);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(file.getPath());
        }
    }

    public static void parseFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for(File child : file.listFiles()) {
                parseFile(child);
            }
        } else if (file.exists()) {
            // Process file here
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(file.getPath()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Which could then be called something like this (using a Windows path, because this Workstation is using Windows):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DirectoryRecurser.parseFile("D:\\raisin");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Error handling here
        System.out.println("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In my case, this prints out:

> File not found: D:\raisin

because said directory is just one I made up.  Otherwise, it prints out the path to each file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apache Commons VFS: http://commons.apache.org/vfs/

Sample:

```
// Locate the Jar file
FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject jarFile = fsManager.resolveFile( "jar:lib/aJarFile.jar" );

// List the children of the Jar file
FileObject[] children = jarFile.getChildren();
System.out.println( "Children of " + jarFile.getName().getURI() );
for ( int i = 0; i < children.length; i++ )
{
    System.out.println( children[ i ].getName().getBaseName() );
}
```

If you need to access files on a network drive, check out JCIFS: http://jcifs.samba.org/

Answer (score 0):

For each file you need to check if it is a directory. If it is, you need to recurse. Here is some untested code, which should help:

```
public void listFiles(File f){
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
    if(f.isDirectory()){
        for (File i : f.listFiles()){
            listFiles(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out buddy

http://java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Traversingallfilesanddirectoriesunderdir.htm

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
  }


  public static void visitAllDirsAndFiles(File dir) {
    System.out.println(dir);

    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
      String[] children = dir.list();
      for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        visitAllDirsAndFiles(new File(dir, children[i]));
      }
    }
  }

}
```